# Manual touch control for Flexslider

Tags: jquery, navigation, touch, customization, flexslider

I've set up a Flexslider (http://woothemes.com/flexslider/) where some of the slides contain video content. On a touch device, these slides can be hard to navigate as they're not swipable because of the embeded video player. I thought of the idea to have a specific touch area below these specific slides that registers previous/next as the user swipes it, but I haven't seen any custom options for this in the Flexslider documentation. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xsGqn/

Basically I am creating an overlay over whole Flexslider surface. It will cover the slider and float over it. Only button next and previous will float over it. Second thing we need is an excellent **[hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js)** framework that will give us swipe functionality. This example is created on a basis of Flexslider 2. Overlay will cover only 70% in height so that video controls can be accessible.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />        
        <script src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
        <script src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/39683393?api=1&player_id=player_1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $(document).hammer().on("swipeleft", ".flex-overlay", function(event) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("next") //Go to next slide
    });

    $(document).hammer().on("swiperight", ".flex-overlay", function(event) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("prev") //Go to previous slide
    });

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        start: function(){
            $('<div>').attr('class','flex-overlay').appendTo('.flex-viewport');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.flex-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.flex-prev, .flex-next{
    z-index: 99999;    
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a thorough answer! I really like this approach, will make sure to implement and try it out asap.
Hopefully the Flexslider team will come up with their own solution in a future version.